# slow local network wireless connection between linux laptops

Tags: networking, router, performance, lan, iperf3

I have two laptops on the same network in my house. I was trying to share files from one to the other via a web server I developed myself(static file sharing). I found it slow and tested the connection speed with iperf3. Result is:

```
$ iperf3 -c 192.168.1.103 -p 4445
Connecting to host 192.168.1.103, port 4445
[  5] local 192.168.1.106 port 39464 connected to 192.168.1.103 port 4445
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bitrate         Retr  Cwnd
[  5]   0.00-1.00   sec  1.94 MBytes  16.3 Mbits/sec   12   39.6 KBytes       
[  5]   1.00-2.00   sec  1.55 MBytes  13.0 Mbits/sec    1   48.1 KBytes       
[  5]   2.00-3.00   sec  1.55 MBytes  13.0 Mbits/sec    1   55.1 KBytes       
[  5]   3.00-4.00   sec   954 KBytes  7.82 Mbits/sec    1   39.6 KBytes       
[  5]   4.00-5.00   sec  1.24 MBytes  10.4 Mbits/sec    0   46.7 KBytes       
[  5]   5.00-6.00   sec  1.55 MBytes  13.0 Mbits/sec    0   48.1 KBytes       
[  5]   6.00-7.00   sec  1.24 MBytes  10.4 Mbits/sec    0   39.6 KBytes       
[  5]   7.00-8.00   sec  1.24 MBytes  10.4 Mbits/sec    0   42.4 KBytes       
[  5]   8.00-9.00   sec   636 KBytes  5.21 Mbits/sec    0   39.6 KBytes       
[  5]   9.00-10.00  sec   636 KBytes  5.21 Mbits/sec    0   35.4 KBytes       
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bitrate         Retr
[  5]   0.00-10.00  sec  12.5 MBytes  10.5 Mbits/sec   15             sender
[  5]   0.00-10.03  sec  11.8 MBytes  9.87 Mbits/sec                  receiver

iperf Done.
```

As seen, the speed is ~10 Mbps. I can download files at 30 Mbps even from internet, and in my modem's manual it says

> Signal Rate: 867Mbps at 5GHz, 300Mbps at 2.4GHz

so I expect much faster speeds.

My modem(ADSL) is **Tp-Link AC1200 VC220-G3u**. I couldn't find any custom setting that limits speed. What can be the problem and how can I fix it?

I run `iperf3` test against a [public iperf server](https://iperf.fr/iperf-servers.php) only on one laptop. For regular client tests, it was around ~7.5Mbps. But my internet package already has 8Mpbs upload limit. For reverse tests (-R) it was ~11Mbps and ~15Mbps.

TBH public servers don't seem that healthy, since most of them gives "Bad File Descriptor" error. Also my problem is about Local Network where the only limiting criteria should be modem's transfer capability. On internet, you are bound to server limits and your ISP package.

Comment: Does your router have any QoS settings or similar? Are you using the latest firmware version? Try to turn off the firewalls.

Comment: Have you checked the `iperf3` results on both systems against a [public server](https://iperf.fr/iperf-servers.php)?

Comment: @harrymc yes my router has QoS settings. On "Basic Settings" there are downstream and upstream settings, but they look disabled. On "SP/WRR Settings" and "Bandwidth Control" pages, there are tables which you can add rules/controls but they are currently empty.

Comment: @Peregrino69 I tried only on one laptop. For regular client tests, it was around ~7.5Mbps. But my internet package already has 8Mpbs upload limit. For reverse tests (-R) it was ~11Mbps and ~15Mbps. TBH public servers don't seem that healthy, since most of them gives "Bad File Descriptor" error. Also my problem is about Local Network where the only limiting criteria should be modem's transfer capability. On internet, you are bound to server limits and your ISP package.

Comment: I've never seen "Bad file descriptor" with `iperf` or `iperf3`. However the public servers can sometimes be hard to reach or not work correctly. Right now iperf.worldstream.nl port 5201 does - I just tested. You're right abt the internet vs. LAN transfer speeds, but testing 1 of the 2 parts of the equation means you know how 1 of the 2 parts work. You still don't know how the other end performs. Please don't answer in comments, but [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1773274/edit) the question instead so relevant info is easily available.

Comment: Can you re-test with one of the laptops being connected via Ethernet?